# How to dispose/delete managed object from C++/CLI

Tags: dll, c++-cli, idisposable

I'm working on a native C++ project (/clr enabled) that must use a couple of managed, COM visible C# DLLs. Some of the managed objects implement IDisposable and I would like to call Dispose() on them. How can I do that?

The code looks something like this:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
IManagedClassPtr pIObj(__uuidof(ManagedClass));
//do stuff with pIObj
...
//dispose of pIObj somehow
...
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: You're mixing COM and C# CLR managed objects.

Comment: Indeed. What would you suggest?

Comment: `IDispose` is handled language-intrinsically in C++/CLI by the finalizer, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you don't have to, just don't use COM.

C++/CLI is designed to give an easy interface between C++ and .Net languages.

If you want to create a .Net object in C++/CLI you just use **[gcnew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8.aspx)** with a reference variable.

.Net classes that have a [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method will have it in C++/CLI too. **[The difference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319826/IDisposable-Finalizer-and-SuppressFinalize-in-Csha)** is that if you declare a ref class (.Net reference class) in C++/CLI then the `~destructor` turns into a Dispose method.
The `!finalizer` is what's actually called by the GC.

So anyway, if you create a .Net object with a Dispose() method, you would be able to do this:

```
MyDisposable^ m = gcnew MyDisposable();
m->Dispose();
```

Comment: The project I'm working on is a COM module. My plan is to write as little C++ as possible and keep all the functionality in managed land. The COM module itself should be a very thin layer that bridges the COM Interface with the C# DLLs. Would your approach work in these circumstances?

Comment: @AlexG. You don't need a COM interface unless you really know how COM works, and all its disadvantages.... You don't need C++ CLI to bridge COM, you can just reference the DLL that contains the COM objects to a C# project.

Comment: Alright, I've explored the C++/CLI approach and you're right. It's definitely much cleaner and more hassle free. Thanks!

Comment: If an `IDisposable` field will get a value in the constructor, but cannot be usefully given a value in a field initializer, is there any nice way to indicate that the auto-generated `Dispose` method should clean it up if non-null?  The only approach I can figure would be to define an exposed-field class-constrained generic struct with a `Dispose` method which calls `Dispose` on its field if non-null, but that would seem awkward.